# How to correctly drop rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have some erroneous data points in my dataset that I need to get rid of (see image, it's very obvious there). So I need to drop rows based on dual condition - when column A is greater or equal 0.5 AND column B equals to 0.

[image]

So I tried:

```py
df = df.drop(df[df['A'] >= 0.5 & df['B'] == 0].index, inplace=True)
```

This results in an error:

```
cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

I then tried to create a mask and drop rows this way:

```py
mask = (df['A'] >= 0.5) & (df['B'] == 0)
df = df.drop(df[mask], axis = 1)
```

This for some reason results in all my data getting deleted save for the index column.

How do I do this properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df = df[(df['A'] <= 0.5) & (df['B'] != 0)]` or in your case: `df = df[~mask]`

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Does "~" here means to invert selection?

Comment: Yes exactly! The link of the duplicate question has tons of valuable information. I suggest you take a ready and also look at the `.query` method.